# Disable timeout on iFrames

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am making a home controller and I am using iFrames to gather the different pages to get everything on the same website. I have one page where I have a remote computer that is not always on, so I have currently made a loading image and a toggle switch while its loading. But after a while the iframe puts out the message "took to long too respond". Can I disable that and make it load forever?

Comment: SO is not a free homework service.

Answer (score 0):

This should help fix it when the source is broken and not loading

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        $("iframe").not(":has([src])").each(function () {

        var ifrm = this;

        ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;

        ifrm.document.open();
        ifrm.document.write($(this).attr("alt"));
        ifrm.document.close();

        });

    });
</script>
```